# How to use GridView edit functionality to modify a field that relies on another field

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, webforms

Sorry for the convoluted title, but that is the best way I could think to phrase it.

Basically, I have a column of data that is a URL (lets call it URL-A), and another that is hidden which is also a URL(URL-B). I have a function called ConvertURL(string URLin) in the codebehind that will take URL-A and turn it into URL-B.

So in this gridview, if someone were to edit an entry using the native gridview/datasource functionality and change URL-A, how do I get it to run this new URL-A through ConvertURL() and update the URL-B field?

Here is a simple representation of the code (not the actual code):

**Code-behind function:**

```
public string ConvertURL(string URLin)
{
    Int32 iLocation = URLin.IndexOf("WWW.XYZ.COM");
    if (iLocation >= 0)
    {
        string checkurl = URLin.Replace("WWW.XYZ.COM", "STAGING.XYZ.COM"); 
        return checkurl;
    }
    else 
    {
        return URLin;
    }
}
```

**Data-Source:**

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:My_AppConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [URL_A], [URL_B], [URLName] FROM [My_App] WHERE ([IsActive] = @IsActive)"
      OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [My_App] SET [URL_A] = @URL_A, [URL_B] = @URL_B, [URLName] = @URLName, [IsActive] = @IsActive WHERE [ID] = @original_ID">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="True" Name="IsActive" Type="Boolean" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="URL_A" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="URL_B" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="URLName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="IsActive" Type="boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_ID" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_URL_A" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_URL_B" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="original_URLName" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**And Lastly the GridView:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing"   
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="ID" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="False" ForeColor="Black" 
        GridLines="Vertical" AllowSorting="True" BackColor="White" 
        BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
        AutoGenerateEditButton="True" CausesValidation="false">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="URL_A" HeaderText="URL A" 
                SortExpression="URL_A" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="URL_B" HeaderText="URL B" 
                SortExpression="URL_B" **Visible="False"** />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="URLName" HeaderText="URL Name" 
                SortExpression="URLName" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsActive" HeaderText="Active" 
                SortExpression="IsActive" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

So to summarize: A user will see a gridview with 3 fields to edit, one of which is URL_A (URL_B is hidden). When they hit edit and update the URL_A field I want to run URL_A through the ConvertURL() function and use that output as the data for URL_B when the update is performed.

I appreciate the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [RowUpdating event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx) of the grid view and change the new value for URL_B. In that event you will have [access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.aspx) to the old values of the row as well as the new values. You can change the new values before they are sent to the data source for the actual update.

Add the event handler to the grid view in the ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    ...
    OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
```

And in the code file handle the event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) 
{
    // Find the current value for URL_A
    string urlA = (string)e.NewValues["URL_A"];
    // Get the corresponding value for URL_B from the method
    string urlB = ConvertURL(urlA);
    // Set the new value for the URL_B column before it's sent to the SqlDataSource
    e.NewValues["URL_B"] = urlB;
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you! That is exactly what i was trying to figure out.